# How to handle the setText("Some Text") event on a disabled TextBox

Tags: events, gwt, textbox

I want to fire an event when setting a value in a TextBox with `setText("something")`

What I tried so far

```
w.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {            
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
    isChanged = true;
}
});
```

And I tried also to have a custom a TextBox that listen to past event

```
class CustomTextBox extends TextBox implements HasHandlers {

 private HandlerManager handlerManager;

 public CustomTextBox() {
     super();        
     handlerManager = new HandlerManager(this);  
     sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);      
 }

 @Override
 public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
   super.onBrowserEvent(event);

   switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
     case Event.ONPASTE:{
      fireEvent(new TextChangeEvent());
       break;
     }
     default:
       // Do nothing
   }
 }

 @Override
 public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
   handlerManager.fireEvent(event);
 }

 public HandlerRegistration addTextChangeEventHandler(TextChangeEventHandler handler) {
   return handlerManager.addHandler(TextChangeEvent.TYPE, handler);
 }
}
```

With no success, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `ONPASTE` experiment a distinct question? I don't quite understand the issue here.

Comment: No, I was thinking the the Paste event can handle the setText("") action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setText` won't fire events.

Add a `ValueChangeHandler<String>` to your `TextBox`, then use `setValue("something", true)` to fire a `ValueChangeEvent<String>` to all handlers while setting the new value, whether the box id disabled or not.

Comment: That's worked ! Is it possible to combine the onBrowserEvent and the addValueChangeHandler(...) on the same TextBox ?